# Setting selection to Nothing when programming Excel

Tags: vba, excel

When I create a graph after using range.copy and range.paste it leaves the paste range selected, and then when I create a graph a few lines later, it uses the selection as the first series in the plot.  I can delete the series, but is there a more elegant way to do this?  I tried

```
Set selection = nothing
```

but it won't let me set selection.  I also tried selection.clear, but that just cleared the last cells that were selected, and still added an extra series to the plot.

Comment: Why not just select the first series?

Comment: What you actually want to do isn't setting selection to nothing (you always have something selected). Instead you want to clear what might eventually be selected *for copying*.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
Cells(1,1).Select
```

It will take you to cell A1, thereby canceling your existing selection.

Comment: I tried this, and it still adds an extra series to the plot.  Interestingly enough, I plot a second graph immediately after this, and it doesn't have the extra series.

Comment: It might not work as intended in several scenarios. If the previously selected cell has been copied to the clipboard it will not (necessarily) do the trick.

Answer (score 50):

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: Excel 2010 VBA- I wanted to deselect a range (ie remove the animated dashed border) after copying and pasting it in vba. The accepted solution didn't work for me (nor curiously for the OP it would seem ??) but this one did.

Comment: +1. This should be the accepted answer as it does exactly what the OP intends to do (avoid using a previously selected cell for copying) - it turns off the "copied cell" marking (dashed line around a cell). And well, worked for me!

Comment: Agreed with Ister - unless I missed the point of the question, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 11):

Just use

> SendKeys "{ESC}"

thereby cancelling your selection.

Comment: This is genius.  Thanks!

Comment: This is a lazy roundabout way to do `Application.CutCopyMode = False`. Don't do this.

Comment: Great answer! It is a direct answer to the question and it also worked in my case. I just think it looks unprofessional that one line in the figure I created with code remains selected.

Comment: This also works, if shapes were selected before.

Answer (score 10):

Select any cell and turn off cutcopymode.

```
Range("A1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a way to SELECT NOTHING that solve your problem.

1. Create a shape (one rectangle)
2. Name it in Shapes Database >>> for example: "Ready"
3. Refer to it MYDOC.Shapes("Ready") and change the visibility to False

When you want that Excel SELECT NOTHING do it:

```
MYDOC.Shapes("Ready").visible=True
MYDOC.Shapes("Ready").Select
MYDOC.Shapes("Ready").visible=False
```

This HIDE the selection and nothing still selected in your window
PLUS: The word "Ready" is shown at the Left Top in your Sheet.

Comment: This *almost* worked for me in Excel 2016, except that now if you set visible to false on the shape, the selection returns to the most recent selected cell. Fortunately in my case the sheet is protected so users can't edit shapes, so this still works out with the shape's visibility set to True but with the shape actually hidden by hiding the column it is in.

Comment: That's kind of brilliant, BUT the shape is still selected. You didn't happen to add the obvious following statement, debug.print Selection is Nothing
which reveals that you still have something selected; it's just hidden. BTW selection.name is also a giveaway here. Further, .RangeSelection still exists, which may be a useful tidbit for some, notably when Selection is not a Range.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use this code at the end. (Do not use False)

```
Application.CutCopyMode = True
```

Answer (score 3):

I do not think that this can be done. Here is some code copied with no modifications from Chip Pearson's site: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/UnSelect.aspx.

UnSelectActiveCell

This procedure will remove the Active Cell from the Selection.

```
Sub UnSelectActiveCell()
    Dim R As Range
    Dim RR As Range
    For Each R In Selection.Cells
        If StrComp(R.Address, ActiveCell.Address, vbBinaryCompare) <> 0 Then
            If RR Is Nothing Then
                Set RR = R
            Else
                Set RR = Application.Union(RR, R)
            End If
        End If
    Next R
    If Not RR Is Nothing Then
        RR.Select
    End If
End Sub
```

UnSelectCurrentArea

This procedure will remove the Area containing the Active Cell from the Selection.

```
Sub UnSelectCurrentArea()
    Dim Area As Range
    Dim RR As Range

    For Each Area In Selection.Areas
        If Application.Intersect(Area, ActiveCell) Is Nothing Then
            If RR Is Nothing Then
                Set RR = Area
            Else
                Set RR = Application.Union(RR, Area)
            End If
        End If
    Next Area
    If Not RR Is Nothing Then
        RR.Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Tried all your suggestions, no luck , but here's an idea that worked for me
select a cell out of your selection range (say AAA1000000)
and then select the A1 again

Range("AAA1000000").Activate

Range("A1").Activate

Guy

Answer (score 1):

In Excel 2007, a combination using select and CutCopyMode property, it is possible to reset all the selections. It worked for my use case.

```
Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy
ActiveSheet.Range("A" & lngRow).Select
```

Regards
Madhur

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with Excel 2013.  I had "freeze panes" set, which caused the problem.  The issue was resolved when I removed the frozen panes.

Answer (score 1):

**If you select a cell in an already selected range,** it will not work. But, Selecting a range outside the original selection will clear the original selection.

'*** The original selection ***'
ActiveSheet.range("A1:K10").Select

'*** New Selections ***'
Activesheet.Range("L1").Select

'*** Then ***'
Activesheet.Range("A1").Select

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub MyFunc()

    Range("B6").Select

    Selection.Locked = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and select a cell out of view and then set the `.ScreenUpdating` to true. This would at least not show any selected cells in the current view.

Answer (score 0):

`Selection(1, 1).Select` will select only the top left cell of your current selection.

Answer (score 0):

If using a button to call the paste procedure,

try activating the button after the operation. this successfully clears the selection

without

- having to mess around with hidden things
- selecting another cell (which is exactly the opposite of what was asked)
- affecting the clipboard mode
- having the hacky method of pressing escape which doesn't always work

HTH

```
Sub BtnCopypasta_Worksheet_Click()
   range.copy
   range.paste
BtnCopypasta.Activate
End sub
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

None of the many answers with `Application.CutCopyMode` or `.Select` worked for me.

But I did find a solution not posted here, which worked fantastically for me!

From StackExchange SuperUser: [Excel VBA “Unselect” wanted](https://superuser.com/questions/469720/excel-vba-unselect-wanted)

> If you are really wanting 'nothing selected`, you can use VBA to protect the sheet at the end of your code execution, which will cause nothing to be selected. You can either add this to a macro or put it into your VBA directly.

```
Sub NoSelect()
   With ActiveSheet
   .EnableSelection = xlNoSelection
   .Protect
   End With
End Sub
```

> As soon as the sheet is unprotected, the cursor will activate a cell.

Hope this helps someone with the same problem!

Comment: No, that's incorrect, at least for my version of XL. It doesn't cause Selection to be Nothing; it remains as is (or just drops down to .RangeSelection if e.g. a shape was selected). You can confirm this with debug.print Selection is Nothing. True, when protected (and I assume you imply that all cells are locked), you cannot manually select cells in the User Interface, and indeed the selection "looks" invisible, but it's still selected. Your code will know that too. A simple way for you to see this is with selection.row and selection.count.

Answer (score 0):

Do statement as below:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveWindow.SplitRow+1,ActiveWindow.SplitColumn+1).Select
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you tried to use a more direct script?

I had the same issue with some code:

```
Columns("C:C").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

Very easy, i know. But now i use:

```
Columns("C:C").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

Since it doesnt select anything, you dont have the green outline anywhere. I dont know if there is a specific function for your use, but if there is this would be the easiest option i think.

Cant you try something like:

```
Range("NewGraph").value = Range("OldGraph").value
```

ps. noob here so i dont know if it makes sense but after learning stuff here im just trying to help some others.