# Selection.clear does not unselect selection

Tags: excel, vba, selection

I want to <s>clear</s> unselect the current selection whenever the user starts "MyMacro".

I'm using the following code:

```
Sub MyMacro()

    If Not IsSheetExists("Memory") Then
        Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).name = "Memory"
    End If

    Sheets("Memory").Visible = xlSheetVisible 'change to xlSheetVeryHidden
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

    ClearAllSheets

    '......
End Sub

Sub ClearAllSheets()
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        sh.Cells.Clear
        sh.Buttons.Delete
        Selection.Clear
    Next sh
End Sub
```

Why doesn't `Selection.Clear`  <s>clear</s> unselect the current selection?

Comment: Have you select some ranges or cells?

Comment: Isn't `sh.Cells.Clear` already clearing everything?

Comment: sam is right, that line should clear everything.

Comment: [INTERESTING READ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Comment: Yes, a cell is selected. I don't know why it is not cleared.

Comment: I did not use select in my code. The purpose of the application is to display data to the user when he selects a certain cell. I want to clear this selection when the user re-runs the macro, or simply when he presses a "next button" which I added to the worksheet.

Comment: by `clear the selection`, do you mean unselect, or clearing the contents

Comment: got it. I thought that selection.clear should unselect, while it clear the selected cells , right? so I should simply google "unselect cell"... SORRY you all!!!

Comment: yea see my answer. And AFAIK, there is no such thing as `unselect` in VBA

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting selection to Nothing when programming Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292779/setting-selection-to-nothing-when-programming-excel)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright,

`.Clear` is meant to clear the contents (& formatting) inside a cell/range, but not unselect

therefore, when you use `Selection.Clear`, nothing happens

As you have mentioned also, why not just select a dummy cell?

Comment: I might be wrong, but AFAIK, there is at least one cell selected at any time on the activesheet

Comment: didn't notice. This is sad :)

Answer (score 1):

`Selection.Clear` doesn't work since you don't have any selected range.

if you code it like this:

```
sh.Cells.Select
Selection.Clear
```

Then it will probably work.
But it is preferable not to use `Select`.

**Update:**
add this:

```
Dim rng as range

Set rng = Selection
```

or in your case:

```
set rng = sh.Application.Selection
```

then execute:

```
Selection.Clear.
```

it will clear the currently selected range.

Comment: I don't understand what's going on. I've tried to select a dummy cell and then clear the selection by using Selection.Clear and it does not clear the selection as well...

Comment: again, for `Selection.Clear` to work, you must select something first. if you want to delete the currently selected cells see my update.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

it works for me

best regard

Comment: That's the most-voted solution for another same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3794312/9150270), I don't understand why here it's downvoted. Please help me close this question as being a duplicate.

Answer (score -3):

try this instead

```
Selection.ClearContents
```

Comment: It will clear the Contents (Values) of the selected Range.