# excel: deselect range after run macro

Tags: vba, excel

I guess there is an easy way to solve this, but I couldn't see it clearly.

Everytime I change any cell in my in sheet it triggers this code below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("A:S")) Is Nothing Then 
copy_column
End Sub
```

This code runs my `copy_column` macro (that copies some columns from my original sheet to another). That first code it happens because I want to automatically update the destination sheet when the origin sheet changes.

```
Sub copy_column()

Set origem = Sheets("FUNCIONÁRIOS").Range("A4:C1040000")
Set destino = Sheets("BASE_TOTAL").Range("A2")
origem.Copy
destino.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Set origem_subs = Sheets("FUNCIONÁRIOS").Range("S4:S1040000")
Set destino_subs = Sheets("BASE_TOTAL").Range("J2")
origem_subs.Copy
destino_subs.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Set origem_ini_fer = Sheets("FUNCIONÁRIOS").Range("L4:L1040000")
Set destino_ini_fer = Sheets("BASE_TOTAL").Range("H2")
origem_ini_fer.Copy
destino_ini_fer.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Set origem_fim_fer = Sheets("FUNCIONÁRIOS").Range("P4:P1040000")
Set destino_fim_fer = Sheets("BASE_TOTAL").Range("I2")
origem_fim_fer.Copy
destino_fim_fer.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

When my macro finishes it lets the last copied column selected like this:

[image]

Is there any way to deselect this column at the end?

Comment: Press escape when you record the macro.  It would  give you `application.cutcopymode = false`

Comment: There are a few ways. You can simply do `Cells(1,1).Select` to select `A1`, or `Application.CutCopyMode = False`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting selection to Nothing when programming Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292779/setting-selection-to-nothing-when-programming-excel)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press escape when you record the macro. 
It would give you:

`Application.CutCopyMode = False`

Edit:
In general, your code does not need Copy and Paste - you only need the values. Thus, something like this will work:

```
Sub copy_column()

    Set origem = Sheets("FUNCIONÁRIOS").Range("A4:C1040004")
    Set destino = Sheets("BASE_TOTAL").Range("A2:P1040002")
    destino.Value = origem.Value

    Set origem_subs = Sheets("FUNCIONÁRIOS").Range("S4:S1040004")
    Set destino_subs = Sheets("BASE_TOTAL").Range("J2:J1040002")
    destino_subs.Value = origem_subs.Value

    Set origem_ini_fer = Sheets("FUNCIONÁRIOS").Range("L4:L1040004")
    Set destino_ini_fer = Sheets("BASE_TOTAL").Range("H2:L1040002")
    destino_ini_fer.Value = origem_ini_fer.Value

    Set origem_fim_fer = Sheets("FUNCIONÁRIOS").Range("P4:P1040004")
    Set destino_fim_fer = Sheets("BASE_TOTAL").Range("I2:P1040002")
    destino_fim_fer.Value = origem_fim_fer.Value

End Sub
```

And it is faster.

Comment: Note - it's not clear from OP, but if they want to "deselect the column", then perhaps just adding say `Cells(1,1).Select` at the end would work.  The `CutCopyMode` will just unselect the range for copying, but still leave that range selected.

Comment: @BruceWayne - I cannot agree more.

Comment: @BruceWayne yes, that is true, I just notice now when I was testing the solution. Anyway, thanks both!

Comment: @Vityata thanks for the edit. Actually, I'm new in VBA so when I did my research it was the best way that I found. I'm glad that is improved now.

Comment: @paulinhax - I am glad I helped. :)