# How to clear paste range after Excel VBA copy and paste?

Tags: excel, vba, selection, paste

I use Application.CutCopyMode = False to clear the Copy range, but the Paste range is still selected.  I hate leaving large ranges selected, so usually I'll just do something like "Range("A1").Select".

But that doesn't work if the target for the paste isn't on the selected sheet, so now I have to select the sheet before selecting another cell.  I think all that is tacky.  There must be a better way to deselect the Paste range, isn't there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting selection to Nothing when programming Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292779/setting-selection-to-nothing-when-programming-excel)

Comment: For example: `PasteRange.Worksheet.Activate: PasteRange.Worksheet.Range("A1").Activate`. You can replace `.Worksheet` with `.Parent` and/or `Activate` with `Select`. If you could share the code, a different solution may be revealed in your specific case.

Comment: Please add your code to understand what could be causing your issue

Comment: It's very simple. I don't think seeing he code will help.
    Sub TEST()

Range("fro").Copy

Range("too").PasteSpecial

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub

After running that, the range "too" is highlighted in gray.  That's what I want to get rid of.  The problem isn't activating the paste range, it's unactivating or deselecting it!

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion in my previous comment? Copy it right after `Application.CutCopyMode = False` i.e. you cannot activate a range (cell) on a not active worksheet.

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  When I do that, I get an error when I try to paste, since the copy range has been cleared.   
<code>Sub TEST()
Range("fro").Copy
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("too").PasteSpecial
End Sub</code>

BTW, how the heck to I highlight the code section? Nothing I try works.